# Dynatrace Service Flow diagram is not working for aks applications

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, azure-aks, dynatrace

By following the Dynatrace documents, we could Set up AKS monitoring via Dynatrace Operator using the manual mode "classicFullStack Installation". we could add the kubernetes workloads  to the dynatrace and able to monitor the infrastructure component like nodes cpu and memory resources and running workloads etc.

But actually we were looking to get the application traces like service flow diagram of apps which are running kubernetes, like what  backend service callings, services response time, traffic flow etc, and etc..

But after installing the operator in AKS and oneagents deployments to the aks nodes,  we are able to get process and workload information , but we are not able to get these services  traces in dynatrace.

```
apiVersion: dynatrace.com/v1beta1
kind: DynaKube
metadata:
  name: myaks
  namespace: dynatrace
spec:
  tokens: mytoken
  skipCertCheck: false
  networkZone: azurezone
  oneAgent:g
    classicFullStack:
      image: ""
      tolerations:
        - effect: NoSchedule
          key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          operator: Exists
        - effect: NoSchedule
          key: node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane
          operator: Exists
  activeGate:
    capabilities:
      - routing
      - kubernetes-monitoring
      - dynatrace-api
    image: ""
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 500m
        memory: 512Mi
      limits:
        cpu: 1000m
        memory: 1.5Gi
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this `g` is just a typo? `oneAgent:g`

After the operator is installed and oneagents are ready you need to restart the workloads so they can load the code module for tracing the service calls.

If you don't see any service calls you should check if activation of deep monitoring was successful on the process page.

Comment: Yes, g was a typo and in actual deployment its correct only. We have restarted the workloads multiple times but its not showing serviceflow diagram, where as the proces and distributed traces we can see. Could you please guide how to check the deep monitoring is enabled?